# Why is window.requestFileSystemSync undefined?

Tags: javascript, cordova, undefined, html5-filesystem

I'm working with [phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com/) API developing in IOS. I need to retrieve the storage directory synchronously. I am trying to use `window.requestFileSystemSync(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT,0)` but `window.requestFileSystemSync` is `undefined`. Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation of PhoneGap v1.1.0](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.1.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#LocalFileSystem), there is only an asynchronous method to do this called `requestFileSystem`.

Answer (score 1):

Two things come to mind:

- did you wait for phonegap device ready event?
- did you include the phonegap.js file in your html page?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that, phonegap does not define sync file system. Will have to do with async version. Thanks.